# What is the purpose of this non-capturing group?

Tags: regex, express

I am trying to understand the inner pipings of [express.js](http://expressjs.com/), but I'm having a little trouble on one thing.

If you add a new route, like such:

```
app.get("/hello/darkness/myold/:name", ...)
```

The string I provided internally becomes a regular expression. Now, I worked out what I thought the regex should be internally, and I came up with:

```
^\/hello\/darkness\/myold\/([^\/]+?)\/?$
```

The `([^\/]+?)` will capture the `name` parameter, `\/?` is present if strict routing is disabled, and the whole thing is encapsulated in `^...$`. However, when I went and looked what is actually stored inside express, it's actually this:

```
^\/hello\/darkness\/myold\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$
```

As you can see, there is a non-capturing group around the capturing group. My question is: what is the purpose of this non-capturing group?

---

The method I used to see what regex express.js was using internally was simply to make an invalid regex and view the error console:

```
app.get('/hello/darkness/myold/:friend/[', function(req, res){});
```

yields

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: ^\/hello\/darkness\/myold\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/[\/?$
```

Comment: You can remove it, it doesn't do anything usefull in this case.

Comment: Someone was high while coding. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that the non-capturing group is a relic of the case where a parameter is optional. Consider the difference between the following two routes:

`/hello/:world/goodbye`

`/hello/:world?/goodbye`

They will generate, respectively:

`^\/hello\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/goodbye\/?$`

`^\/hello(?:\/([^\/]+?))?\/goodbye\/?$`

Note the important but subtle change that happens to the non-capturing group when an optional parameter is present.